# how to remove ^m symbol

Tags: debian, bash, sh

I need to compile Qt under Debian 64-bit. I downloaded sources but there is ^M symbol everywhere in every file in the end of lines and bash doesnt run configure script. How to remove it from all files in qt sources? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `dos2unix` - it will convert your file to unix newline syntax

Answer (score 4):

Yes, use dos2unix. Note that `^M` is a carriage return, also denoted as `\r`. Another way to remove them is

```
sed -i 's/\r$//' file ...
```